# Why the members of the domain object (POCO) are defined virtual?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, domain-driven-design, repository-pattern

In the pluralsight video of http://www.asp.net/mvc. The model object member were changed to virtual in the middle of a video. He didn't give detail description of the change. Could any one elaborate the necessity?

```
public class Restaurant
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
}
```

BTW, is the `IDBContext` in the video follows repository pattern? Should the code use repository pattern for best practice if it's not?

```
public interface IDbContext
{
    IQueryable<Restaurant> Restaurants { get; }
    IQueryable<Review> Reviews { get; }
    int SaveChanges();
    T Attach<T>(T entity) where T : class;
    T Add<T>(T entity) where T : class;
    T Delete<T>(T entity) where T : class;
}
```

---

Update: It should be a variety of repository pattern. Usually repository pattern create one class for one model object `IRepository<T>`. This one put all the model object in one interface `Restaurants`, `Reviews`. How this one compares with the typical one?

Comment: A POCO should never be a domain object. In your example, every entity is a PERSISTENCE model, not DOMAIN. And the repository pattern DOESN'T create one class for one model object. It provides an abstraction and acts as a facade for the persistence access, in this case the EF orm.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To summarize this, to get POCO works with EF, it creates proxy classes that inherit from your original entity classes (POCOs). And so it needs the properties to be virtual in order to override them so that it can plug EF change tracking and lazy loading infrastructure work.
Otherwise no change tracking or lazy loading would be enabled by default.

For complete answer to this you might need to read [Working with POCO Entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456853.aspx) and [Requirements for Creating POCO Proxies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd468057.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

When using Entity Framework, properties must be virtual in order to support lazy loading.

Answer (score 1):

From the [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd468057.aspx);
"For change tracking proxies:

Each property that is mapped to a property of an entity type in the data model must have non-sealed (NotOverridable in Visual Basic), public, and virtual (Overridable in Visual Basic) get and set accessors."